# TFS command line client default location

Tags: tfs, command-line-interface, tf-cli

If I'm using the TFS command line client is it *always* located @ **<drive>:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE**?  I'm referencing [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, depends on VS version installed (and don't forget 64 bit machines too)

Answer (score 3):

For reference only,My default location is
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE**
vs2010,win7,64 bit

Answer (score 2):

No it is not. E.g. on my machine it is under c:\VS10\Common7\IDE. You can use environment variables VS100COMNTOOLS (for VS 2010) and VS90COMNTOOLS (for VS 2008). The location of the tfs command line tools would be

```
"%VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\IDE\tf.exe"
```

-- for VS 2010

```
"%VS00COMNTOOLS%\..\IDE\tf.exe"
```

-- for VS 2008

Comment: hmm, I don't have those in my default install of VS200(8?).  I'm aware you can run a script to set them, but I'm looking for something that's there out of the box and is in a predictable location (like a script, the client itself, or an environment variable)

Comment: tf.exe is only available if the Team Explorer client is installed on top of Visual Studio.  In 2008 this was not part of the default install and you have to install it separately from the tfc folder on the Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite (or one of the Team editions), from the Team Foundation Server media or from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0ed12659-3d41-4420-bbb0-a46e51bfca86&displaylang=en

Comment: How did you install VS? VS90CMNTOOLS variable is created automatically once you install VS 2008. It is in system environment block, which means it affects all users.

Answer (score 1):

In VS2008, tf.exe will be available under C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE